# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18) adding to Dictionary from HealthKit data

Tags: swift, dictionary, healthkit

Been trying to debug this for an entire day. The crash is seemingly random and intermittent. Sometimes it can loop for 100x and no crash, sometimes 2 loop is enough to crash it.

I have placed an exception breakpoint but no matter what I do, it always fails when it tries to update the Dictionary. If I were to comment this out, No Crash.

```
consolidatedData[quantityTypeIdentifier] = averageByDay
```

Here's the relevant codes

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit

class HealthStore {
  var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
  
  // Define static unitMappings
  static let unitMappings: [String: (HKUnit, (Double) -> Double)] = [
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass.rawValue                : (HKUnit.gramUnit(with: .kilo), {$0}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.restingHeartRate.rawValue        : (HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute()), {$0}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRateVariabilitySDNN.rawValue: (HKUnit.secondUnit(with: .milli), {$0}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.oxygenSaturation.rawValue        : (HKUnit.percent(), {$0 * 100}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureSystolic.rawValue   : (HKUnit.millimeterOfMercury(), {$0}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureDiastolic.rawValue  : (HKUnit.millimeterOfMercury(), {$0}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyFatPercentage.rawValue       : (HKUnit.percent(), {$0 * 100}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount.rawValue               : (HKUnit.count(), {$0}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned.rawValue      : (HKUnit.kilocalorie(), {$0}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.basalEnergyBurned.rawValue       : (HKUnit.kilocalorie(), {$0}),   // restingEnergy
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMassIndex.rawValue           : (HKUnit.count(), {$0}),

    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate.rawValue               : (HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute()), {$0}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.leanBodyMass.rawValue            : (HKUnit.gramUnit(with: .kilo), {$0}),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceCycling.rawValue         : (HKUnit.meter(), {$0})
  ]
  
  
  static let healthToIntIcuWellnessMapping: [String : (dataType: String, unit: String)] = [
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass.rawValue                : ("weight"         , "kg"),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.restingHeartRate.rawValue        : ("restingHR"      , "bpm"),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRateVariabilitySDNN.rawValue: ("hrvSDNN"        , "ms"),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.oxygenSaturation.rawValue        : ("spO2"           , "%"),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureSystolic.rawValue   : ("systolic"       , "mmHg"),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureDiastolic.rawValue  : ("diastolic"      , "mmHg"),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyFatPercentage.rawValue       : ("bodyFat"        , "%"),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount.rawValue               : ("Steps"          , ""),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned.rawValue      : ("ActiveEnergy"   , "kcal"),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.basalEnergyBurned.rawValue       : ("RestingEnergy"  , "kcal"),
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMassIndex.rawValue           : ("BMI"            , "")
  ]
  
  
  init() {
    if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
      healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    }
  }
  
  func readHealthKitData<T: HKQuantityType>(quantityType: T, startDate: Date, endDate: Date, completion: @escaping ([HKQuantitySample]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    // Check if HealthKit is available on the device
    guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
      completion(nil, NSError(domain: "com.someApp", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "HealthKit is not available on this device."]))
      return
    }
    
    // Create a predicate to query samples within the specified date range
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)
    
    // Define the query to retrieve quantity samples of the specified type
    let query = HKSampleQuery(
      sampleType: quantityType,
      predicate: predicate,
      limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
      sortDescriptors: nil
    ) { (query, results, error) in
      if let error = error {
        completion(nil, error)
        return
      }
      
      if let samples = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {
        completion(samples, nil)
      } else {
        completion(nil, NSError(domain: "com.someApp", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to retrieve data."]))
      }
    }
    
    // Execute the query
    HKHealthStore().execute(query)
  }
  
  
    func getHealthDataForMultipleTypes(quantityTypeIdentifiers: [HKQuantityTypeIdentifier], startDate: Date, endDate: Date, completion: @escaping ([HKQuantityTypeIdentifier: [String: Double]]) -> Void) {
      var consolidatedData: [HKQuantityTypeIdentifier: [String: Double]] = [:]
      let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
      
      var queryResults: [HKQuantityTypeIdentifier: [String: Double]] = [:] // Collect query results

      for quantityTypeIdentifier in quantityTypeIdentifiers {
        dispatchGroup.enter()

        // Convert the identifier to HKQuantityType
        if let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: quantityTypeIdentifier) {
          readHealthKitData(quantityType: quantityType, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate) { (samples, error) in
            if let samples = samples {
              var dataByDay: [String: [Double]] = [:]

              for sample in samples {
                let dateStr = FormatDisplay.date_yyyymmdd(sample.startDate, format: "yyyy-MM-dd")
                if let (unit, conversion) = HealthStore.unitMappings[sample.quantityType.identifier] {
                  let value = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit)
                  let convertedValue = conversion(value)
                  dataByDay[dateStr, default: []].append(convertedValue)
                }
              }
              
              // Calculate average per day
              var averageByDay: [String: Double] = [:]
              
              for (dateString, values) in dataByDay {
                averageByDay[dateString] = self.getDailyValue(values, dataType: quantityTypeIdentifier)
              }
             
              
              // Use a DispatchQueue to synchronize access to consolidatedData
              let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.HealthDataQueue")
              queue.async {
              
                  // FAILS HERE
                  // It always crashes here with -->  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
                  consolidatedData[quantityTypeIdentifier] = averageByDay
                  dispatchGroup.leave()
              }
              
              
            } else {
              print("No data found for \(quantityTypeIdentifier)")
              dispatchGroup.leave()

            }
          }
        }
      }

      dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(consolidatedData)
      }
    }


  private func getDailyValue(_ samples: [Double], dataType: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier) -> Double {
    let dailyValue: Double
    
    switch dataType {
    case .stepCount:
      // For other quantity types, calculate the sum
      dailyValue = samples.reduce(0.0, +)

    default:
      let dailyTotal = samples.reduce(0.0, +)
      dailyValue = dailyTotal / Double(samples.count)

    }

    // Round the result to the closest one decimal point
    let roundedValue = (dailyValue * 10).rounded() / 10
    
    return roundedValue
  }
  
}
```

This is how I am calling it

```
let healthStore = HealthStore()
let todayDateStr = FormatDisplay.date_yyyymmdd(Date())
let syncFromDate = FormatDisplay.addingDayTo_yyyymmddTimestamp(inputDate: todayDateStr, addDay: -7)
let quantityTypeIdentifiers: [HKQuantityTypeIdentifier] = [.bodyMass, .bodyFatPercentage, .leanBodyMass, .bodyMassIndex, .activeEnergyBurned, .basalEnergyBurned, .heartRateVariabilitySDNN, .oxygenSaturation, .bloodPressureSystolic, .bloodPressureDiastolic, .restingHeartRate, .stepCount]

for i in 0...100 {
  healthStore.getHealthDataForMultipleTypes(quantityTypeIdentifiers: quantityTypeIdentifiers, startDate: syncFromDate, endDate: Date()) { (returnedData) in
    counter += 1

    // Initialize the parsedData dictionary
    var parsedData: [String: [String: Double]] = [:]
    
    for (field, data) in returnedData {
      for (date, value) in data {
        if parsedData[date] == nil {
          parsedData[date] = [:]
        }
        parsedData[date]?[field] = value
      }
    }
    
    print("counter:\(counter) seq:\(i) Data:\(parsedData)")
    }
  }
}
```

I'm running this on Xcode 14.3.1 with the simulator running iOS15.5 and this is how the results looks like when it works.

```
counter:1 seq:0 Data:["2023-09-18": ["weight": 57.0], "2023-09-19": ["ActiveEnergy": 2.0, "weight": 55.0, "bodyFat": 3.0], "2023-09-16": ["weight": 53.0], "2023-09-21": ["bodyFat": 2.5, "RestingEnergy": 22.2, "weight": 52.7], "2023-09-20": ["bodyFat": 4.0], "2023-09-15": ["weight": 62.4, "bodyFat": 5.9]]
```

[image]

reading [SwiftLee's article](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/thread-sanitizer-data-races/) I turned on `Thread Sanitizer` and It pointed to the offending line

```
(lldb) thread info -s
thread #35: tid = 0xb50a13, 0x0000000113a51170 libclang_rt.asan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`__asan::AsanDie(), queue = 'com.example.HealthDataQueue', stop reason = Deallocation of freed memory

{
  "access_size": 0,
  "access_type": 0,
  "address": 106377752394688,
  "description": "double-free",
  "instrumentation_class": "AddressSanitizer",
  "pc": 0,
  "stop_type": "fatal_error"
}
```

So it looks like it's a data race condition? How do I fix it? I've already used `dispatchQueue` and `dispatchGroup`

Answer (score 1):

Experienced this crash, but the problem was that NSMapTable was being used that isn't thread safe (according to Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html)

So to access it during asynchronous calls, the DispatchQueue().async {} method worked. Probably a race condition.